# Extract daily area average value of ERA-5 minimum temperature of 30 years using GEE?

Tags: raster, google-earth-engine, java, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, climate

I'm struggling in finding a way to extract daily minimum temperatures for a particular month (at present for january) and a study area (an imported shapefile as chamoli), for a selected period of time (1990-2021(30 years)). For now, I have extracted the daily minimum temperature for the study area. I need to have one average value for each day of the study area as table.

```
`var era5_2mt = ee.ImageCollection('ECMWF/ERA5/DAILY')
               .select('minimum_2m_air_temperature')
               .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(1990,2021,'year'))
               .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(1,1,'month'));
               var study_area = era5_2mt.map
                (function(era5_2mt){
                  return era5_2mt.clip(table);
                });
              var vis2mt = {
              min: 250,
              max: 320,
              palette: [
                   '#000080', '#0000D9', '#4000FF', '#8000FF', 
                   '#0080FF', '#00FFFF', '#00FF80',
                   '#80FF00', '#DAFF00', '#FFFF00', '#FFF500', 
                   '#FFDA00', '#FFB000', '#FFA400',
                   '#FF4F00', '#FF2500', '#FF0A00', '#FF00FF'
                     ]
                     };
              Map.addLayer(study_area,vis2mt);
```

[GEE code link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/?scriptPath=users%2Fshravanibanerjeemitali%2Fminimum_temperature%3Acold_waves)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Geometry in your asset is not available so, I assumed one arbitrarily in USA. For 'minimum_2m_air_temperature' in Celsius degrees, following [code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/3b990d100cf724da02dde8108c08ab48) works as expected.

```
var geometry = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[-106.62578125, 37.316033269641146],
          [-106.62578125, 35.97625743920629],
          [-104.780078125, 35.97625743920629],
          [-104.780078125, 37.316033269641146]]], null, false);

var era5_2mt = ee.ImageCollection('ECMWF/ERA5/DAILY')
                   .select('minimum_2m_air_temperature')
                   .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(1990,2010,'year'))
                   .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(1,1,'month'));

var era5_2mt_list = era5_2mt.toList(era5_2mt.size());

print(era5_2mt_list);

var study_area = era5_2mt_list.map(function(img){
  
  var date = ee.Date(ee.Image(img).get('system:time_start')).format().slice(0, 10);
  img = ee.Image(img).subtract(273.15);
  
  // Reducing region and getting value
  var value_temp = ee.Image(img)
    .reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.mean(), geometry)
    .get('minimum_2m_air_temperature');
  
  return [date, value_temp];
  
});

var vis2mt = {
  min: -20,
  max: -10,
  palette: [
    '#000080', '#0000D9', '#4000FF', '#8000FF', '#0080FF', '#00FFFF', '#00FF80',
    '#80FF00', '#DAFF00', '#FFFF00', '#FFF500', '#FFDA00', '#FFB000', '#FFA400',
    '#FF4F00', '#FF2500', '#FF0A00', '#FF00FF'
  ]
};

var image = ee.Image(era5_2mt_list.get(0))
  .subtract(273.15)
  .clip(geometry);

print(image);

Map.centerObject(image);
Map.addLayer(image, vis2mt);

print(study_area);

var myFeatures = ee.FeatureCollection(study_area.map(function(el){
  el = ee.List(el); // cast every element of the list

  return ee.Feature(null, {
    'date': el.get(0),
    'temp_min': el.get(1),
  });
}));

print(myFeatures);

// Export features, specifying corresponding names.
Export.table.toDrive(myFeatures,
"CSV_Export", //my task
"GEE_Folder", //my export folder
"mean_temp_jan",  //file name
"CSV");
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick help.